# Automatically change type in mysql

Tags: mysql

Table test

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `sd` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

if I search with this query

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id="1A"
```

found 1 row with id = 1 but 1A not equal 1.
What should I do that's query find correct.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: You should compare like-to-like.  If the field is an integer, then pass in an integer value, and only an integer value.

Comment: What is your expected output ? and why are you trying for 1A when ID is increment with 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM test WHERE id LIKE '%1A%'
```

have tried your query looks return 1 :) . but you should search for integer values or use `LIKE` statment

Comment: it's actually the other way round. `id` is of type integer, so you should ensure the searched variabel is a int, not cast id to string.

Comment: are you sure that a like operation works on an integer column?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify

```
 WHERE id = '1A'
```

you're telling MySQL to compare an `int` (the type of your `id` column) to a character string. In fact, you're implicitly telling MySQL to do this:

```
WHERE id = CAST('1A' AS INT)
```

The value of `CAST('101A' AS INT)` is the integer 101.  The value of `CAST('A101' AS INT)` is the integer zero.  This implicit typecasting can be troublesome because it happens silently. You need to be careful about this.

To search for an integer the best way to do it is this:

```
WHERE id = 1
```